# Probabilistic method exercise

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The following exercise appeared in my exam which i could not solve.

> Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be a sequence of iid real random variables such that $$P(X_i=0)=p,P(X_i=1)=q,P(X_i=2)=r$$ where $p+q+r=1$.Let $X= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{X_i}{3^i}$.Compute $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$ then deduce  that unless $p=q=r=\frac{1}{3}$ there exist $a,b \in (0,1)$ such that $p(a<x<b )\neq b-a$

I computed that $E(X)=\frac {q+2r}{2}$.Is this correct ? For the second part the hint was given to use probabilistic method but i could not solve it.Any ideas to do it?

Comment: You might want to add that to the question. Your computation of $EX$ is correct.

Comment: Also, are the probabilities for $X_1$ supposed to be for $X_i$? (In other words, are the probabilities for each $X_i$ the same?)

Comment: @Duncan: iid  means independent & **identically** distributed.

Comment: Ah, true. Didn't catch that. Thanks, @copper.hat.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks.I have edited the question.The question asked to compute the $EX^2$ also

Comment: Ahhh... "and $E(X^2)$" This makes more sense now. Just compute $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$ and solve the system $E(X)=\frac12$, $E(X^2)=\frac13$ for $(p,q,r)$.

Comment: @Did: I really dont follow your comment.Could you explain how does this solve and how to compute $E(X^2)$?

Comment: "I really dont follow your comment." This s odd... How to compute $E(X^2)$? Expand $X^2$ as a sum of terms $X_i^2$ and $X_iX_j$, compute $E(X_i^2)$ (independent of $i$) and $E(X_iX_j)$ (independent of $i\ne j$), and do the sum.

Comment: @Did's hint was to note that if the distribution is uniform, then $EX, EX^2$ have certain values.

Comment: @copper.hat: But i dont understand why he is taking $E(X)=1/2$ and $E(X^2)=1/3$.

Comment: If $X$ was uniform on $(0,1)$ then what would $EX, EX^2$ be?

Comment: @copper.hat: Yeah $EX=1/2$ and $E(X^2)=1/3$ thanks,have i computed $E(X_i^2)$ and $E(X_iX_j)$ correct?

Comment: @Dontknowanything: $E[X_i X_j] = E X_i EX_j$ for $i \neq i$.

Comment: Maybe using $var(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$ is helpful.

Comment: Or $\operatorname{var} X = \sum_k \operatorname{var} ( { X_k \over 3^k})$?

Comment: @copper.hat,  Also, Dominated Convergence Theorem to justify the interchange of the limit and the expectation.

Comment: @copper.hat: See the calculation in the answer below seems like even $p=q=r=1/3$ does not satisfy $E(X)=1/2$ and $E(X^2)=1/3$ right?

Comment: @Dontknowanything: It is messier than I expected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take at this problem:

**Edit: I made a mistake on the value of $\bar X_i$. It should be $q+2r$, not $\frac{q+2r}{2}$**.

$Var({X_i}) = (0-\bar{X_i})^2P(X_i = 0) + (1-\bar{X_i})^2P(X_i = 1) + (2-\bar{X_i})^2P(X_i = 2) $

$= (1-q-r)(q+2r)^2 + q(1-(q+2r))^2 + r(2-(q+2r))^2  
= -q^2-4 q r+q-4 r^2+4 r= V$.

Now, $$Var(X) = Var(\sum\frac{1}{3^i}X_i) = \sum \frac{1}{(3^i)^2}Var(X_i) = V\sum\frac{1}{9^i} = \frac{V}{8}.$$

$$E[X^2] = E[X]^2 + Var[X] = \left(\frac{q+2r}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{V}{8} = \frac{1}{8}(q^2+4 q r+q+4 r^2+4 r).$$

Comment: Thanks ,did you try to solve $E(X)=1/2$ and $E(X^2)=1/3$ ?I think $p=q=r=1/3$ does not satisfy this.

Comment: @Dontknowanything Could you explain why $E(X^2) = 1/3$, please?

Comment: If $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ then $E(X^2)=1/3$ using the same formula Var$(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$.

Comment: For the last part of the problem assuming uniform we are computing possible value for $p,q,r$.

Comment: @grixor: $X$ takes values in $(0,1)$. The $X_i$ are the ternary expansion digits.

Comment: @copper.hat My bad. You're correct!

Comment: @Dontknowanything I have corrected my solution. Now, $E(X^2) = 1/3$ when $p = q = r = 1/3.$

Comment: @grixor: I have noticed it.Thank you (+1)

Comment: @Dontknowanything, I suggest you accepting this answer, because mine is just a simplification of this computation.

Comment: @i707107 Thank you guys! As a newbie, I appreciate all the +1's!

Answer (score 3):

Things work out as @Did pointed out. 
We have
$$\mu=E(X)  =\frac{q+2r}2=\frac12,$$
$$\mu_1=E(X_1)=q+2r =1,$$
$$\sigma_1^2=var(X_1)=q+4r-\mu_1^2$$

$$\sigma^2=var(X)=(var(X_1)) \cdot \frac18=\frac{q+4r-\mu_1^2}8 = \frac1{12},$$

Then we have
$$
1 + 2r -1 = \frac23.
$$
This gives $p=q=r=1/3$.

Comment: +1: Nice answer. Any comment on the 'probabilistic method' suggestion?

Comment: Since most of idea is already discussed in the comments, I left out details, just put computation part.

Comment: Well, the above is more explicit than the 'probabilistic method' would usually entail...

Comment: @i707107: Thank you,+1 of course!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach to the last part of the question. I think this
is more in the spirit of the suggested 'probabilistic method':

Let $P$ be the distribution of $X$ on $\Omega = \{ (\omega_1,...) | \omega_k \in \{0,1,2\} \}$. We have $X_k(\omega) = \omega_k$, of course.

Note that $P \{ \omega \} = 0 $ for any $\omega \in \Omega$ unless one of the $p,q,r$ are
exactly one.

Clearly, if one of the $p,q,r$ are exactly one, then $P$ is not uniform.

So, suppose this is not the case.

Note that $X(\omega ) \in (0,{1 \over 3} )$ **iff** $X_1(\omega) = 0$ and
$(X_2(\omega),X_3(\omega),....) \neq (2,2,2,...)$, and similarly, mutatis
mutandis,
for the intervals $({1 \over 3}, {2 \over 3})$, $({2 \over 3}, 1)$.

Then $P(0,{1 \over 3} ) = p, P({1 \over 3}, {2 \over 3}) = q$ and 
$P({2 \over 3}, 1) = r$, from which the desired result follows.

Comment: Ah beautiful..thanks a lot!